# Refine SQL Query given list of ids

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, with-statement

I am trying to improve this query given that it takes a while to run. The difficulty is that the data is coming from one large table and I need to aggregate a few things. First I need to define the ids that I want to get data for. Then I need to aggregate total sales. Then I need to find metrics for some individual sales. This is what the final table should look like:

```
ID | Product Type | % of Call Sales | % of In Person Sales | Avg Price | Avg Cost | Avg Discount
A  | prod 1       | 50              |   25                 |   10      |   7      |    1
A  | prod 2       | 50              |   75                 |   11      |   4      |    2
```

So % of Call Sales for each product and ID adds up to 100. The column sums to 100, not the row. Likewise for % of In Person Sales. I need to define the IDs separately because I need it to be Region Independent. Someone could make sales in Region A or Region B, but it does not matter. We want aggregate across Regions. By aggregating the subqueries and using a where clause to get the right ids, it should cut down on memory required.

IDs Query

```
select distinct ids from tableA as t where year>=2021 and team = 'Sales'
```

This should be a unique list of ids

Aggregate Call Sales and Person Sales

```
select ids
    ,sum(case when sale = 'call' then 1 else 0 end) as call_sales
    ,sum(case when sale = 'person' then 1 else 0 end) as person_sales
from tableA
where
    ids in t.ids
group by ids
```

This will be as follows with the unique ids, but the total sales are from everything in that table, essentially ignoring the where clause from the first query.

```
ids| call_sales | person_sales
A  |    100     |    50
B  |    60      |    80
C  |    100     |    200
```

Main Table as shown above

```
select ids
    ,prod_type
    ,cast(sum(case when sale = 'call' then 1 else 0 end)/CAST(call_sales AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) * 100 as DECIMAL(10,2)) as call_sales_percentage
,cast(sum(case when sale = 'person' then 1 else 0 end)/CAST(person_sales AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) * 100 as DECIMAL(10,2)) as person_sales_percentage
    ,mean(price) as price
    ,mean(cost) as cost
    ,mean(discount) as discount

from tableA as A
where
   ...conditions...
group by
   ...conditions...
```

Comment: You need sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what the query should be doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the first two queries as:

```
select ids, sum( sale = 'call') as call_sales,
        sum(sale = 'person') as person_sales
from tableA
where
    ids in t.ids
group by ids
having sum(year >= 2021 and team = 'Sales') > 0;
```

I'm not exactly sure what the third is doing, but you can use the above as a CTE and just plug it in.

Comment: so use my first query as a CTE as well? The third query is the main query, what everything will feed into.

Comment: I combined the first two queries as suggested into a CTE. The CTE had a subquery in it to get the distinct ids. This query was then inner joined onto the main query to create the main table. Still takes about 3 minutes to run, but more complete than before. Thank you.